# Validating phone numbers with international code in objective-c using RMPhoneFormat

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to validate phone numbers with the international code by using the RMPhoneFormat class developed by rmaddy. It works fine for a US number for example:

```
RMPhoneFormat *fmt = [[RMPhoneFormat alloc] initWithDefaultCountry:@"us"];
BOOL valid = [fmt isPhoneNumberValid:@"+19998887766"];
```

However, for a Swiss number (where the leading zero is removed when using the international code, i.e. 0779998877 becomes +41779998877) does work. The following code says that the number is invalid even though it isn't.

```
RMPhoneFormat *fmt = [[RMPhoneFormat alloc] initWithDefaultCountry:@"ch"];
BOOL valid = [fmt isPhoneNumberValid:@"+41779998877"];
```

Note that without the international code and with the leading zero, it is correctly validated:

```
RMPhoneFormat *fmt = [[RMPhoneFormat alloc] initWithDefaultCountry:@"ch"];
BOOL valid = [fmt isPhoneNumberValid:@"0779998877"];
```

Does anybody know how to use this class to validate phone numbers with the international code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just added the `isPhoneNumberValid` method to `RMPhoneFormat` less than 24 hours ago. It appears there is a bug. Please post a bug report on the github project page. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - this is now fixed. In the future, please report issues or ask questions using github. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect thanks! It works like a charm! I will ask through the bug report next time :)